# How to specify a reference to the state which has parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following routing configuration:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('courses',
        {
            url: '/courses',
            templateUrl: '/js/courses/courses.html',
            controller: 'CoursesCtrl'
        })
        .state('courses.course',
        {
            url: '/{courseId}',
            templateUrl: '/js/courses/course.html',
            controller: 'CourseCtrl'
        })
        .state('courses.course.lessons',
        {
            url: '/lessons',
            templateUrl: '/js/courses/lessons.html',
            controller: 'LessonsCtrl',
        })
        .state('courses.course.about,
        {
            url: '/about,
            templateUrl: '/js/courses/about.html'
        })
    ;
});
```

I have a reference in the page like this

```
<a ui-sref="courses.course({courseId: c.id})"> Course # {{c.id}}</a>
```

This reference leads to the view of the course’s details.
This view has a nested view, which allows seeing different detail of the course such as lessons list and description. I want to have a direct reference to the view, which contains lessons list of the particular course.

I’ve tried something like ui-sref="courses.course({courseId: c.id}).lessons", but it leads to the error.

Could you tell me what is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the syntax

```
<a ui-sref="courses.course.lessons({courseId: c.id})"> Course # {{c.id}} lessons </a>
```

and check you have defined parent state or not..

Comment: Sorry, I can't see your html in the answer.

Comment: you made issue in syntax.

Comment: courses.course({courseId: {{c.id}}}) works well too

Unfortunately, you don’t understand what I am asking.
I need to jump to the child state - courses.course({courseId: c.id}).lessons. However, it doesn’t work and leads to the error.

Comment: then you please post the whole route config..?

Comment: I've posted. Please look.

Comment: <a ui-sref="courses.course.lessons({courseId: c.id})"> Course # {{c.id}}</a>

Comment: Thanks so much! That's what exactly I wanted! ))